# How to overwrite remote outdated branch on git with master branch?

Tags: git, github

is it possible to overwrite remote outdated branch on git with master branch by removing all remote commits and update needed branch with latest changes from master branch?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the remote branch to look like a local branch, in history and contents, then just push the local branch into the remote branch:

```
git push -f the-remote local-branch:remote-branch
```

*Again*, that will set history and contents like your current branch. This means, if it's not obvious, that you are more than likely rewriting history.

Answer (score 0):

that's what I exactly searched

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout dev_branch
git reset --hard master
git push --force
```